# Unable to boot following upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04. Gave up waiting for root file system device error

Tags: boot, 22.04

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 on a dell XPS 420. When I try to boot ubuntu I get the following error message:

Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc.cmdline)
-check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=eda9825d-f1ac-427f-b587-250a6895b43d does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

All previous solutions I can find for this answer indicate that the SATA configuration in the BIOS must be changed to AHCI, however I cannot find a way to do this in the BIOS for Dell XPS 420.

Comment: You need to boot form a LiveUSB and fix UUID in fstab. It is not related to AHCI.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair